# Did Firefox running in Mac OS X get hacked

Tags: macos, firefox, security, osx-lion, virus

When I try to do a Google search in Firefox, I can't click on any of the links. They're just regular black text, not hyperlinks. I even tried safe mode and disabling all the plugins. I was running Firefox 12. I installed the current version over it and it's the same thing. Other browsers have not been affected.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

My firewall was turned off, and I had several things running which are potential security holes. I turned on my firewall and closed all unnecessary ports. I also turned off Home Sharing. Then I restarted my computer. After that, Firefox works normally again.

What do you think happened?

Comment: Make sure that you run OS X Software Update and install the Java patch, if you haven't done so. It fixes a Java security issue. This said, I don't think that you were hacked, this looks more like a CSS or settings issue. Downgrading Firefox, it usually messes things up even further.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this with some older versions of Firefox on a Mac. Eventually, it could help to delete all system files of Firefox inside your library folder and install it again. (But first backup your data!) But just to say, I just had to update to the newest version of Firefox (eventually deleting cache + cookies might also help).

I don't think that Firefox got hacked (but of course it could be possible)...

Answer (score 2):

Create a new Firefox profile and see if the problem persists.

1. Quit Firefox completely
2. Open **Terminal** and type `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -profilemanager` (assuming Firefox is installed in your Applications folder)
3. Click the *Create Profile...* button and follow the prompts.
4. Select the new profile and click the *Start Firefox* button.